# Can I keep myself joined to an irc channel even after exiting my client?

Tags: irc, chat, irssi

Is leaving a channel when exiting and joining when a new session starts considered proper?
I am asking this because I have only used Discord as I do not usually need real-time communication. I have used IRC in the past (not very frequently), however I always left all joined channels before exiting. Is this considered normal? If not, what can I do to keep myself joined to a channel even after exiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IRC, if you close the client, all channels are automatically left. The only reason to part a channel prior to exiting the client, is so you can set a speficic exiting message.

You `/part Goodbye, was a lot of fun` and it will say something like "User left channel saying: Was a lot of fun".

On IRC you only are connected to a server/channel as long as you are physically connected, and every time you reconnect, you have to manually join those channels again, which is why you create startup scripts to automatically join several channels and servers.

IRC is one of the very first chat systems that dates back to the 80 if I recall correctly. There was little experience in what chatting was, and when people found it a hastle to keep joining servers and channels without a script, other chat applications came bye that changed this. They introduced friends lists and later joining on a server, which is what Discord is today.

> Is this considered normal? If not, what can I do to keep myself joined to a channel even after exiting?

Given that IRC simply does not have this natively, if you want to keep connected to an IRC server, you need a client somewhere that stays connected. This can be an IRC bouncer. The IRC bouncer connects to a server and you connect to that bouncer. The bouncer relays messages back and forth and even though you close your IRC client, the bouncer does not. So when you connect back, you also get a history of what has been said before up to x lines.

To run a bouncer, you DO need something that stays connected to the internet and is always on, like a server. It is possible to run a bouncer through a rasphberry pi or similar small computer.